# Incremental backup tar error

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, tar

I'm making a backup system.

I have 2 servers : the **main sends data** to the backup server, then, the **backup server compress** the data. To save disk usage, I just compress the files that have changed thanks to a `flag-file` that stores the last backup time.

**Sometimes it works fine**, but sometimes my script is exiting with an `error 123`This error is comming from `xargs`

The description is :
`123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125`

So the `command` I launch is :

`find /home/* -name "." -not -path "/home/*/www/cache/*" -not -path "/home/*/www/cc/cache/*" -not -path "/home/*/www/ot/cache/*" -not -path "/home/backups/*" -newer /var/backups/data/flagfile -print0 | xargs -0 -r tar -czvf /home/backups/incremental/H14/backup.tar.gz`

When I do this : 
`find /home/* -name "*.*" -not -path "/home/*/www/cache/*" -not -path "/home/*/www/cc/cache/*" -not -path "/home/*/www/ot/cache/*" -not -path "/home/backups/*" -newer /var/backups/data/flagfile -print0`

It returns a list of files like expected.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code :

`find /home/* -name "." 
    -not -path "/home/*/www/cache/*" -newer /var/backups/data/flagfile -print0 > files.txt`

Then the tar command :

`tar czvf /home/backups/incremental/H14/backup.tar.gz --files-from files.txt --quoting-style=shell`

The `--quoting-style=shell` escapes special chars so the tar doesn't exit.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to redirect the list of files to a text file first, call it `files.txt`

```
find /home/* -name "." 
    -not -path "/home/*/www/cache/*" 
    -not -path "/home/*/www/cc/cache/*" 
    -not -path "/home/*/www/ot/cache/*"
    -not -path "/home/backups/*" 
-newer /var/backups/data/flagfile -print0 > files.txt

tar -czvf /home/backups/incremental/H14/backup.tar.gz ...
```

Any user can write some pretty weird filenames to your system by uploading
    to their website.

When `xargs` crashes look at the file with a hexviewer and check for non ascii characters ;)
       also which version of xargs are you using...

Comment: thanks for your answer. So the version of xargs is 4.4.2 
I've done just like you said. But instead of using xargs I launch this command : `tar -czf archive.tar -I list.txt`

Comment: I hope it works, the point was to check for bad filenames by looking in the files.txt. Here is a link, [link](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) to the xargs man page particularly the bug section. It looks good, too.

Comment: another issue is that a file can be removed during the run.